# On item creation in Discussion List send email with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, list-item, discussion-board

I am working on discussion list, i am **trying to send the item link to the users with JavaScript, as soon as the item is created.**

But i can find something like, Post Save Action.

Any suggestion on this.?

Comment: why u dont use workflow?

Comment: I can use SPD WF but the problem is i have to check in which group the created by user exists, and accordingly the email will be sent to with GroupId@org.com, but the designer does not provides the from field in the SPD WF.

Comment: If you are on SharePoint Online, you can create a Flow to do that :  send email when new item is added.  You can specify the From field there as well.